# Concentration of sulfur in turbid solution

Tags: inorganic-chemistry, physical-chemistry, kinetics, analytical-chemistry, reference-request

I recently participated in an experiment where I need to calculated the reaction orders and the reaction constant of the reaction:

$$\ce{8 Na2S2O3(aq) + 16 HCl(aq) -> S8(s) + 8 SO2(g) + 16 NaCl(aq) + 8 H2O(l)}$$

by measuring time until the solution becomes too turbid for light to travel through the fluid. Calculating the orders of reaction was possible using proportions of the known starting concentrations and time.

In order to calculate the reaction constant, I need to know a specific change in the concentration of the sulfur (I assumed that this is the element that makes the solution turbid), but I couldn't find any information on the internet. If there is no exact answer, what would be an acceptable estimate?

My data is: measured time until turbidity as a function of changing initial thiosulfat concntration (while initial HCl con. remains constant), and data with reversed roles for HCl and thiosulfat. Need to find the constant of reaction k.

Comment: $\ce{S8}$ is very insoluble in aqueous solution. So assume that there is a constant particle size as more of the  $\ce{S8}$ is created. Does this help?

Comment: You cannot "find" concentration of sulfur directly. You have to use turbidity as proportional to concentration of sulfur.

Comment: Im not sure what do you mean... I tried alot but there is no way to escape this mathematically. The orders of reaction can be calculated only using initial concentration proportions but its not enough for calculate k (reaction constant), the lab guide says nothing on the matter

Comment: I really think you do not need sulfur conc. You need to plot the initial sodium thiosulfate concentration on x-axis and 1/time on the y-axis. This is why nobody is talking about sulfur concentration.

Comment: I doesn't make sense to me... the time is measured until the water is turbid (I draw X on paper and wait until I can't see it), the t is not directly related to the initial thiosulfate concentration.

Comment: Add details what you have *exactly* done in detail in the original post. Nobody can guess what you were doing.

Comment: Sorry, added now

Comment: Okay, so you have several initial concentrations of thiosulfate and you must have notice the time of turbidity. You do *not* need sulfur concentration. See this one 
Kinetics of Thiosulfate in Acid www.science.purdue.edu › science-express › labs › labs. Google this title, the first result should solve some of your problems. It is a word file.